# npm request module error 'This dependency was not found:'

Tags: node.js, module, request

I'd like to use web crawler in JS.
I found request and cheerio module.
I installed them but request module is not working in my program

error is

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors  10:59:36    
This dependency was not found: * fs in ./~/request/lib/har.js    
To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs
```

so I did `npm install --save fs` as well but it's not working with the same message.

code is

```
getTravelSherenum: function () {
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var url = 'http://news.nate.com/recent?cate=pol&mid=n0201&type=c&date=20170702';
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?